# Javascript to generate table with some html tags as part of some columns

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am trying to generate a table based on data sent from the server using java script.

Below is the HTML code:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="updatePCRAnalysis" name="datafixfrm">
 <div class="table-responsive">
 <table id="tabledata" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    {% for d in description %}
     <td> <b>{{ d[0].decode('utf-8') }} </b> </td>
    {% endfor %}
    <td> <b> Investigator </b> </td>
    <td> <b> Remarks </b> </td>
    <td> <b> Status </b> </td>
    <td> <b> Submit </b> </td>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <script>addBody({{dataList}})</script>
  </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
</form>
```

Below is the javascript code:

```
    function addBody(dataList){
      var body =  $("#tabledata").find('tbody');
      for (i = 0; i < dataList.length; i++) {
        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        for (j = 0; j < dataList[i].length; j++) {
          var cell = document.createElement('td');
          cell.textContent = decode_utf8(dataList[i][j]);
          row.appendChild(cell);
        }
        var cell1 = document.createElement('td');
        cell1.textContent = '<input class="form-control" name="investigator" type="textfield">';
        row.appendChild(cell1);
        var cell2 = document.createElement('td');
        cell2.textContent = '<td> <input class="form-control" name="remarks" type="textfield"> </td>';
        row.appendChild(cell2);
        var cell3 = document.createElement('td');
        cell3.textContent = '<select name="flag"> <option value="N">New</option> <option value="X">Exclude</option> <option value="D">Raise Defect</option> </select>';
        row.appendChild(cell3);
        var cell4 = document.createElement('td');
        cell4.textContent = '<button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>';
        row.appendChild(cell4);
        body.appendChild(row);
      }
      return body;
    }
```

Most of the code I found here in stackoverflow usually specifically for the table to have data filled up in the cells. For this table, I need to fill last 4 columns with textfield, option box, and submit button.

Not sure if this approach is right as this is my first javascript program. Thanks!

**Update: 01-Mar-2016**

Apparently I was getting a Javascript error:

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '&'
```

I thought that it might be due to non UTF-8 data, so I added a function to convert the value to convert to urf-8 format and changed the part in the original function to "**cell.textContent = decode_utf8(dataList[i][j]);**"

```
    function decode_utf8(s) {
      return decodeURIComponent(escape(s));
    }
```

**Update: 03-Mar-2016**

Updated the parameter of the function call:

```
    <script>
      addBody({{dataList|tojson|safe}});
    </script>
```

Updated the variable assignment of the tbody and the cell.textContent to cell.innerHTML:

```
    function addBody(dataList){
      var tbody = document.getElementById('tabledata').getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
      ...
      ...
      var cell1 = document.createElement('td');
      cell1.innerHTML = '<input class="form-control" name="investigator" type="textfield">';
      row.appendChild(cell1);
      var cell2 = document.createElement('td');
      cell2.innerHTML = '<td> <input class="form-control" name="remarks" type="textfield"> </td>';
      row.appendChild(cell2);
      var cell3 = document.createElement('td');
      cell3.innerHTML = '<select name="flag"> <option value="N">New</option> <option value="X">Exclude</option> <option value="D">Raise Defect</option> </select>';
      row.appendChild(cell3);
      var cell4 = document.createElement('td');
      cell4.innerHTML = '<button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>';
      row.appendChild(cell4);
      tbody.appendChild(row);
      ...
      ...
    }
```

Comment: What specific problems are you having?

Comment: the data is not showing in the table.

Comment: Why not? Is there a problem with `dataList` in your Flask application? (You haven't shared your view, so who knows what it's doing.) Is there a JavaScript error inside `addBody`?

Comment: thanks for your replies. i have updated my question to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: Are you sure `dataList` is rendering the way you expect? You may need to escape the data, e.g., `{{ dataList|tojson|safe }}`.

Comment: @dirn - that worked in removing the error. Just had to fix getting the tbody tag and assigning using cell.innerHTML instead of cell.textContent.